# MongoDB with Apache Solr: Should you index entire collection in Solr? If not then how to get the complete document based on solr index search query

Tags: solr

---

I am using apache solr for field based and for full text search as well.
Should I index entire collection of mongodb in Solr?

If i decide to index only selected fields out of a document of mongo collection in apache-solr, then will I be able to get the complete document from indexed search query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the properties fields can have in Solr are `indexed` and `stored`. In a high level simple way, indexed means they are processed and searchable, stored just means their original content is saved as is and can be retrieved. So for example, you can index the entire MongoDB document into a stored Solr field, then index various other parts of the document into indexed fields. So you could search on those indexed fields, and get the entire document back from the stored field in the result.

Note: fields can be both indexed **and** stored

Comment: Thanks. If I understand your response, I am duplicating the data in solr. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes technically. However, the indexed fields are broken up and processed and go to creating the inverse index. So while words or phrases within documents are duplicated between fields in that sense, there would only be 1 field that has the entire original, unaltered content in it. And that's fine.

Comment: Understood. Additionally, Could you please reply to the second question? "If i decide to index only selected fields out of a document of mongo collection in apache-solr, then will I be able to get the complete document from indexed search query?"

Comment: No, you won't. If only parts of the document are indexed in Solr, you couldn't possible retrieve or recreate the entire original document, because there are parts missing. The most you could get is the parts you indexed, in their original form. In order to get the entire original document in its entirety, you have to store it. Otherwise where would it come from? Solr wouldn't know what the missing pieces were